# Game crashing on Sony Xperia

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sony-xperia

Phone: Sony Xperia LT25i.

I installed game. Launched it. Saw black screen and unresponsive application.

And logcat keep spamming in console:

```
W/Adreno-EGL(23297): <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateContext:2342>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
W/Adreno-EGL(23297): <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateContext:2342>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
I/Unity   (23297): Skipped frame because GfxDevice is in invalid state (device lost)
I/Unity   (23297):  
I/Unity   (23297): (Filename:  Line: 1585)
I/Unity   (23297):
```

Does anyone have idea whats going on and how to fix this?

I tried different apps. I even created empty project with empty scene - same result.

Comment: A new Unity project yields the same result on that phone? What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Yes. Unity3d version: 5.0.0f4. Phone's android version: 4.3 (probably Sony custom)

Comment: Is the new Unity project created by Unity 4.x crash on this phone? I suspect that this bug is device-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was resolved by updating Android SDK and installing previous SDK versions.